# String 'expanding' - reinserting repeating characters

Tags: java, beginner, strings, programming-challenge

The challenge: Given a String, for each digit in that original string, replace that digit with that many occurrences of the character following it. So `a3tx2z` yields `attttxzzz`.

My Solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Standford1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter string to blowup: ");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(blowup(userInput)); 
    }

    public static String blowup(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (!isNumeric(str.substring(i, i + 1))) {
                sb.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
            else {
                sb.append(lengthen(str.charAt(i + 1), 
                    Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i + 1))));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static String lengthen(char c, int i){
        if (i == 0 || c == ' ') { return ""; }
        int count = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(c);
        while (count != i) {
            sb.append(c);
            count++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Could this be more readable? I alternate a lot between char and string (it seems optimal, am I wrong?), but should I just stick with one? Any and all feedback/suggested revisions/general optimizations welcomed with gratitude.

**Edit**: Stay within the specifications of the challenge. In the case of a number following a number this code is WAI i.e. the correct yield of blowup("a231") results in "a33111."

**Edit 2**: End digits just get ignored, since they have nothing to repeat, i.e. blowup("a2x3") would yield "axxx" - I realize I overlooked this case due to a question below, I have now amended this, but left the original question and code intact.

**Edit 3**: These should all be true:

```
/* Two plain cases */
System.out.println("Test 1: " + "xxaaaabb".equals(blowup("xx3abb")));
System.out.println("Test 2: " + "xxxZZZZ".equals(blowup("2x3Z")));
/* digit at the end */
System.out.println("Test 3: " + "axxx".equals(blowup("a2x3")));
/* Adjacent digits */
System.out.println("Test 4: " + "a33111".equals(blowup("a231")));
/* Digit include 0 */
System.out.println("Test 5: " + "aabb".equals(blowup("aa0bb")));
/* Unusual Characters */
System.out.println("Test 6: " + "AB&&,- ab".equals(blowup("AB&&,- ab")));
/* Empty String */
System.out.println("Test 7: " + "".equals(blowup("")));
/* Only digits */
System.out.println("Test 8: " + "".equals(blowup("2")));
System.out.println("Test 9: " + "33".equals(blowup("23")));
```

**Note**: So this isn't incorrectly perceived as a 'do this for me' question, as stated in edit 2,  I've already accounted for all cases.

Comment: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your instincts are good here, in almost all respects. Your basic algorithm is good, and your suspicions that you are changing too often between `String` and `char` is also good.

Using the `StringBuilder` is the right thing to do; well done. Breaking the `String` into chars is also good, but the way you do that is inconvenient.... In part that's because there is a convenient function in the standard Java `Character` class that you will find useful: [`Character.isDigit(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-)

With that function, you can throw out your `isNumber()` function, and simplify the whole thing down to chars, strings, and ints.... something like:

```
public static String blowup(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int repeat = 0;
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            repeat = repeat * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(c);
        } else {
            while (repeat > 0) {
                sb.append(c);
                repeat--;
            }
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

(I put this in an [Ideone here](http://ideone.com/xq0Oft))

Note that it also keeps a counter outside the loop. This removes the need for the 'ugly' `i + 1` offset on a repeating character count.

The code still assumes valid input (where the last character cannot be a digit, or it is lost). Additionally, I tweaked it to handle multiple digit input.... like `"20z"` ... for fun.

---

**Update:** In my mind, I immediately 'threw out' your `isNumeric()` method, because it was not needed... but I have only now just read it.... Eeugh! Yuck!

You should never use exception handling (`try`/`catch`) to handle normal program flow. The try/parse/catch logic you have is very slow to run. Throwing an exception for every non-digit character will be a lot of overhead. Even though Java has improved in terms of performance, when processing exceptions, it is still much slower than the alternatives, like a regular expression, or some other mechanism...

**Update 2**: working with the original specs (thus ignoring the multi-digit repeat), the code would be (here in [a different Ideone](http://ideone.com/pdl8yN)):

```
public static String blowup(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int repeat = -1;
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (repeat < 0 && Character.isDigit(c)) {
            repeat = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        } else {
            do {
                sb.append(c);
            } while (--repeat >= 0);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Notes for this version:

1. Uses `repeat` as a flag set to negative for nothing. This allows for input like `ab01` which will output `ab1` (which would be impossible without the 0-repeat option).
2. Note that the repeat is now also used as a flag for the `isDigit` check.
3. a `do`-`while` loop instead of a `while`-`do` loop (as per Josay's comment).

Comment: Nice answer ! Two quick questions about the while-do loop : 1. Any reason for it not to be a for loop ? (as it does look like a for loop) 2. Any reason for it not to be a do-while ? (as it would remove the duplicated line of code)

Comment: @Josay - I considered the do-while loop, but found it woud be awkward to get the decrementing 'repeat' counter to work without it becoming negative, and impacting the 'sexy' double-digit handling. As for the 'for' loop, there is no need for an additional variable, so it seems gratuitous, but I would not be against it...

Comment: Your 'fun' part is actually outside the specifications of the challenge. blowup("a231") should result in "a33111".

Comment: This made me realize this code doesn't accurately account for whether the last digit is a number though, thank you.

Comment: Would you explain the ` repeat = repeat * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(c);` line? I can follow what's happening otherwise but 10 * 0 + x??

Comment: that's just the 'fun' add-on of multi-digit expansions... let me remove it and simplify it back to your original specs..s ... 3 minutes.

Comment: @Legato - added a second update to my answer.

Comment: This actually fails the adjacent digit case (see first edit), or digit only case:

`blowup("a231")` should result in "a33111" and
`blowup("23")` should yield "33".

With your code, I get "333" for the latter and "a333" for the former.

Comment: @Legato - then your original specification in your code is wrong.... not my answer. Your specification says `a3tx2z` expands to `attttxzzz` thus, `3t` expands to 3 t's follwed by a t. This matches the words as well: *replace that digit with that many occurrences of the character following it*. Thys, my code replaces `23` with 2 3's, followed by the 3 -> `333`

Comment: Unlike other characters, ending digits have nothing to replace, so they're dropped, or 'multiply by 0'. I added the more obvious example for a reason  blowup(a231) yielding a333 is clearly incorrect.  a + two instances of 3 + three instances of 1 + one of nothing. Despite the misunderstanding, I accepted your answer, It's well written and gave me the most insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A few inputs:

- Are you handling exceptional cases as in say,

  1. A string ends with a number.
  2. A string contains character other than {0-9,a-z,A-Z}
  3. Null or empty string.
- Is there any upper limit to the value of number say, if the string is "a99999999". Since, your implementation expects one number after a character, is it a limit defined by you or is it pre-decided?
- Be uniform with your approach, i.e `Integer.parseInt` has a try..catch in `isNumeric` and not in `blowUp()`
- Also, `charAt()` at some places and `substring` at some?

I would go by the code of rolfl. It deftly handles all the behaviour.

Comment: I asked about that. I preferred charAt in all places available, for obvious reasons, but the parseInt method takes a str, I wasn't aware of the `Character.isDigit` method for the first use and otherwise my Lengthen method needed parseInt for its second parameter, but given the char method I looked it up and found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char