# Finding the length of the largest run

Tags: java, beginner, strings, programming-challenge

**Note**: A run is a series of adjacent chars that are the same.

I just want to answer a few questions:

1. Is this readable?
2. Does it need commenting or is it self-descriptive enough?
3. Are there any efficiency tweaks this could have?
4. Is this a good way to test?
5. Which is the preferred/conventional syntax?

```
int maxCheck = 0,
    maxRun = 1,
    currentRun = 1;`
```

**vs.**

```
int maxCheck = 0, maxRun = 1, currentRun = 1;
```

**vs.**

```
int maxCheck = 0;
int maxRun = 1,
int currentRun = 1;
```

I surmise this probably varies from individual to individual, but for this challenge in particular my instincts were to exclude spaces, but the challenge didn't specify this, and in the [last challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75094/string-expanding-code-challenge-reinserting-repeating-characters): my intuition, just as the first answer, also wanted me to include digits larger than 9, but that was actually 'wrong' and outside of the specifications of the challenge -- as was evidenced with failed tests (provided by the challenge).

Should I just take 'requirements' literally most of the time to avoid constructing technically 'incorrect' code? I ask since the tests in this case don't include spaces, and it's definitely something I'm wondering in case of larger, more abstract projects.

```
public class Standford2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test 1: " + (1  == maxRun("123")));
        System.out.println("Test 2: " + (2  == maxRun("1223")));
        System.out.println("Test 3: " + (2  == maxRun("112233")));
        System.out.println("Test 4: " + (3  == maxRun("1112233")));
        System.out.println("Test 5: " + (2  == maxRun("hoopla")));
        System.out.println("Test 6: " + (3  == maxRun("hoopllla")));
        System.out.println("Test 7: " + (3  == maxRun("abbcccddbbbxx")));
        System.out.println("Test 8: " + (0  == maxRun("")));
        System.out.println("Test 9: " + (3  == maxRun("hhhooppoo")));
    }

    public static int maxRun(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 0) { return 0; }

        int maxCheck = 0,
            maxRun = 1,
            currentRun = 1;

        if (str.length() == 1) { return maxRun; }

        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i - 1)) {
                currentRun++;
                if (currentRun > maxRun) { maxRun = currentRun; }
            }
            else { currentRun = 1; }
        }
        return maxRun;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `maxCheck` variable is unused.  You also don't need the `str.length() == 1` special case.

The whitespace around the `else` is unconventional.

The efficiency is fine.  Your algorithm, like any reasonable algorithm for this problem, is O(*L*), where *L* is the length of the input string.  You could try to squeeze out a small performance improvement, but it's almost certainly not worth it.

For a simple function like this, I don't think you need code comments.  However, a JavaDoc comment would always be useful.

The code works equally well on any [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/CharSequence.html), not just a `String`, and should therefore be generalized.

```
/**
 * Finds the length of the longest run of identical characters.
 */
public static int maxRun(CharSequence seq) {
    if (seq.length() == 0) { return 0; }

    int maxRun = 1,
        currentRun = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < seq.length(); i++) {
        if (seq.charAt(i) == seq.charAt(i - 1)) {
            currentRun++;
            if (currentRun > maxRun) { maxRun = currentRun; }
        } else {
            currentRun = 1;
        }
    }
    return maxRun;
}
```

The tests that you wrote are fine for a beginner, but the *de facto* standard for Java is to use [junit](/questions/tagged/junit).

Comment: I definitely see the appeal of CharSequence over just String. Bookmarked JUnit for future perusal. Any comments on point 5 or is it up to preference/lacking standard convention?

Comment: The style of declaration/definition is a matter of personal preference. However, you need to ensure that you get the punctuation correct — two of your three samples don't compile.